# Weekend extraction in Matlab

Tags: matlab, weekday

i have a matrix "timeVectorDaily" that is 364 x 5 in size. This matrix has data in form of decimal days.
Eg

```
734870 734870.2 734870.4 734870.6 734870.8
734871 734871.2 734871.4 734871.6 734871.8
```

so on

I need to extract only the weekend rows from "timeVectorDaily". The way i coded to find out if it was a weekend or not is by using the weekday function which returns integers 1 through 7 representing Sunday through Saturday. The array "arrayAllDay" that is 364 x 1 in size has this information.
Eg

```
1
2
```

so on

I have only gotten through to this stage.Can someone help me on how to proceed from here? I need to extract the 1 X 5 for every weekend (1 or 7 returned by the weekday function)

```
j = length(timeVectorDaily);
arrayAllDay = zeros(j,1);
counter = 0;
for m=1:j
    [arrayAllDay(m)] = weekday(timeVectorDaily(m));
    if arrayAllDay(m) == 1
        counter = counter+1;
    elseif arrayAllDay(m) == 7
        counter = counter+1;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

We can find which elements in the `weekday` function fall on a weekend by checking to see if the first column of your matrix when inputted into this function outputs a `1` or a `7`.  Once we do this, this will give us which rows we can select out from `timeVectorDaily`.

Without further ado:

```
arrayAllDay = weekday(timeVectorDaily(:,1));
loc = arrayAllDay == 1 | arrayAllDay == 7;
weekendRows = timeVectorDaily(loc,:);
```

`arrayAllDay` contains numbers from `1` to `7` that tell you what day of the week that number falls on.  `loc` is a logical array where `1` denotes that the day falls on a weekend and `0` where it doesn't.  Finally, `weekendRows` will contain all rows that correspond to weekends.  As such, this will produce a `M x 5` matrix, where `M` are the total amount of weekends that correspond to the first column of your matrix.

BTW, referring to @Shai, it is inadvisable that you use `i` and `j` as iteration variables as these are used for representing complex numbers.  See this link here: [Using i and j as variables in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab) .  Doing so will shadow over these complex variables, and if you do any complex analysis later on, you may get unpredictable results.

Comment: @user3698120 Do you require any further assistance?

Comment: @user3698120 You haven't accepted an answer for any of your questions. Please note that you should accept an answer if it satisfies your needs (and only in that case).